# Cannot find module '../../assets/women.jpg' in react while importing dynamically

Tags: reactjs

I have a data.js file in the assets and it has some images with infos, but when I try to pass the path of the image to the prop I get the error above.
I checked the path and it works fine.

This is data.js

```js
export const categories = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "WOMEN",
    img: "../../assets/women.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "MEN",
    img: "../../assets/men.jpg",
  },

  {
    id: 3,
    title: "CHILDREN",
    img: "../../assets/children.jpg",
  },
];
```

and this is my component

```js
import React from 'react'
const CategoryItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
        <div className='category-item-container'>
            <img src={require( `${ item.img }`)} />
            <p>
                {item.img}
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CategoryItem
```

Answer (score 0):

In react, we want to store our filepaths as variables that we can then inject into our JSX whenever we want. I'd make sure to have import statements above your exported array.
Here are the React docs with concise examples.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

Answer (score 0):

Try to import your image

```js
import women from "../../assets/women.jpg"
import men from "../../assets/men.jpg"
import children from "../../assets/children.jpg"
export const categories = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "WOMEN",
    img: women,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "MEN",
    img: men,
  },

  {
    id: 3,
    title: "CHILDREN",
    img: children,
  },
];

const CategoryItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
        <div className='category-item-container'>
            <img src={item.img} />
            <p>
                {item.img}
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CategoryItem
```